# Разбор сортировки слиянием

Tags: c++, сортировка

У меня есть программа сортировки слиянием, где я считаю число инверсий. В функции main просто создается массив, в который считывается количество элементов массива и сами элементы из входного файла. А затем в выходной файл выводится число инверсий.
Я понимаю, как работает сортировка слиянием и что такое инверсии, но мне не понятно, как сама программа это делает:
1)В функции `merge_sort_1` мы разбиваем наш массив на левую и правую часть, а затем левую и правую также делим пополам, пока не останутся массивы, в которых будет ровно два элемента, а  затем мы все эти элементы передаем в функцию `merge_sort_2` и в ней все эти массивы сливаются и сортируются? Если это так, то как именно работает `merge_sort_1`?
Я пробовал сам на листочке расписать этот алгоритм подставив в первую функцию сам массив, левую и правую границы, но из этого ничего не получилось, я не увидел каким образом наш массив делится пополам. И когда мы пишем

```
merge_sort_1(array, left, middle);
merge_sort_1(array, middle, right)-
```

если, например исходный массив равен `4 3 2 1`, то после этих функций должно быть два массива `[4 3]` и `[2 1]`? Если это так, то куда записываются эти два массива, если здесь один массив `array`, который мы передаем потом в `merge_sort_2`?
Если мы работаем постоянно в одном массиве, просто благодаря `middle` мы делим массив, то тоже не понятно, что в итоге должно получиться после этих функций. И что мы в конце концов передадим в функцию `merge_sort_2`? Мы пишем - `merge_sort_2(array, left, middle, right);`
первое, что мы передаем - это `array`, т.е. наш массив. А что именно в нем будет находиться, после выполнения тех двух функций, а также в каждом из параметров, который мы передаем в функцию `merge_sort_2`, например, если у нас был массив `4 3 2 1`?
Эта функция должна разбить эти массивы на два `4 3`   и  `2 1`, но как эти два массива могут быть в одном `array`? Если же в `array` в это моменте будет `4 3 2 1`, то какой вообще смысл этой функции?

2. Почему именно такая формула у числа инверсий? Я опять же пытался сам на листочке, подставив значения разобраться. Я подставил массив `4 3 2 1`, тут 6 инверсий. Но по такой формуле я насчитал только 4

3)Зачем мы вообще делаем условие `while`? Я понимаю, что мы это делаем на тот случай, если левая сторона не дошла до середины или правая сторона не дошла до конца. Мне не понятно, почему такая ситуация может произойти.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long long amount;

void merge_sort_2(vector<int>& array, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    vector<int> copy;
    copy.resize(right - left);
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (((left + i) < middle) && ((middle + j) < right))
    {
        if (array[left + i] <= array[middle + j])
        {
            copy[i + j] = array[left + i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            copy[i + j] = array[middle + j];
            amount += middle - (left + i);//формула для вычисления числа инверсий 
            j++;
        }
    }

    while ((left + i) < middle)
    {
        copy[i + j] = array[left + i];
        i++;
    }
    while ((middle + j) < right)
    {
        copy[i + j] = array[middle + j];
        j++;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < (i + j); k++)
    {
        array[left + k] = copy[k];
    }
}

void merge_sort_1(vector<int>& array, int left, int right)
{
    if ((left + 1) >= right)
    {
        return;
    }

    int middle;

    middle = (left + right) / 2;

    merge_sort_1(array, left, middle);
    merge_sort_1(array, middle, right);

    merge_sort_2(array, left, middle, right);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream input("inversions.in");
    ofstream output("inversions.out");
    int n;

    input >> n;

    vector<int> array;
    array.resize(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        input >> array[i];
    }

    merge_sort_1(array, 0, n);

    output << amount;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
amount += middle - (left + i);//формула для вычисления числа инверсий
```

Если мы попали в это место кода, то мы передвигаем элемент из правой части, исправляя таким образом указанное справа число инверсий, поскольку элементы от `left + i` до `middle` больше этого самого копируемого элемента.

```
4 3 2 1 
сливая 4 и 3, двигаем тройку, получаем [3 4]   + 1 инверсия
сливая 2 и 1, двигаем единицу, получаем  [1 2]  + 1 инверсия
сливая [3 4] и [1 2], получаем +2 инверсии, двигая единицу на две позиции, 
и ещё две инверсии, двигая двойку на две позиции. 
Всего 6
```

Остальное относится к классической сортировке слиянием, и разжёвано в куче книг и курсов по алгоритмам.